# What is the original form of libiamo in the song "Libiamo, libiamo ne' lieti calici, che la bellezza infiora"?

Tags: word-meaning, grammar

Hi I know nothing about Italian language.
We have to do a lip sync opera for this Christmas and we'll this "Libiamo, .." song. :)
I looked up 'libiamo' in the internet Italian dictionary but couldn't find.
What is the original form of the word and what does it mean?
and I would also be grateful if someone teach me what the words mean in the phrase word by word.
Thank you!

Comment: What do you mean by “the internet Italian dictionary”?

Comment: it's a Italian-Korean dictionary  by naver.com (https://dict.naver.com/itkodict/#/main) and I tried Collins Italian-English dictionary. I don't know the conjugation of Italian so can't find the root word.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Libiamo* comes from the verb *libare*, it is the exortative imperative.
*Libare* is a literary verb, as you can see in the following link to the Treccani dictionary:

https://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/libare1/

It means 'to drink' with an accent on delightful drinking, as in a feast.

The beginning of the text is :

> Libiamo, libiamo ne' lieti calici, che la bellezza infiora
>
> E la fuggevol, fuggevol ora s'inebri a voluttà.

This could be translated this way:

*Let's drink from our joyful glasses, which beauty adorns,*

*And let the fleeting moment be inebriated by voluptuousness.*

This is, in *La Traviata*,  the toast of Violetta in a feast. She is sick of phthisis and knows she is going to die.  So, she  remembers  that time is fleeting.

Comment: Great answer! Only, I feel that, in the libretto authors' pretentious Italian (here, Francesco Maria Piave) _a voluttà_ might mean “at will, as much as one wants” as in _a piacere_, _a piacimento_, _a volontà_. What do you think?

Comment: Grazie mille! It is possible that you are right about 'a voluttà', this opera librettos have a particular language, let say teh truth, as literary   value they are poor poetry.

Comment: But it seems to me more plausible the interpereation 'inebriated by voluptuousness',  I also found a paraphrase that translated this way. And the term 'voluttà' doesn't seem to me to have the meaning of wiil in italian, but of  intense pleasure only. See https://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/volutta/. Moreover, this interpretation is more consistent with the context of sensual love that caracterizes that aria of Violetta.

Comment: Thanks alot!  I;m at work but I'll check later.

Comment: @BakerStreet: _Piacere_ too, in itself, mostly points to (physical etc.) pleasure, but in the phrase _a piacere_ it just means “as much as you want”, even said of bread or salt. What bothers me is that _a_ isn't an usual way to introduce the “subject” of an impersonal verb. But you never know.

Comment: I think you are right, I was uncertain and I looked for a paraphrase, evidently the paraphrase was wrong. 'a' as agent complement seemed odd to me, but this language of opera can be strange, I 'm not expert of opera and I wonder what kind of italian is this .I suppose it is a literary, rethoric language of second class, maybe with desuete features. Think that we have had in literature Leopardi! Maybe a sort of academic language, it comes to mind the academic paintings of '800, terrible paintings with horses and battles, at the same time there was impressionism. But I really don't konw.

Comment: Anyway,  l''ora che si inebria voluttà' seems to me horrible, ' 'be inebriated by voluptuosness' non è male! Con 'l'ora si inebri a piacere' il riferimento sembra solo a una sbronza, si perde l'aspetto sensuale/sessuale. Ma tant'è!

Comment: Mi viene in mente un uso di 'a' in italiano che potrebbe quadrare con il verso, intendendo 'inebriarsi' nel senso di 'impregnarsi', non di 'ubriacarsi', e così lo avevo inteso. Si può dire 'impregnato a vino', 'bagnato a liquore' e roba simile, come si dice 'trattato a ' qualcosa. In questo caso 'inebriato  a volutta' potrebbe significare 'impregnato di voluttà'. che, ripeto, mi sembra più coerente con il testo. Resto nell'incertezza. Ci penserò su e farò qualche altra ricerca per capire.

Comment: Comunque 'inebriarsi' può anche avere significato figurato, 'inebriarsi a volontà' non nel senso di una sbronza ma figurato. Ci penserò, resto nel dubbio su quest ainterpretazione  'a volontà'. Ma forse solo perché non mi piace affatto il verso così, bruttissimo.

Comment: Ho cercato su internet altre parafrasi e traduzioni, tutte quelle che ho trovato tranne una in inglese che mette 'at will', mettono 'by voluptuousnes' per l'inglese e cosa simile in francese. Il fatto è che non trovo una fonte davvero autorevole. Metto questo sito, con traduzione in francese "Buvons, buvons dans ces joyeuses coupes,
Que la beauté fleurit ;
Et que l'heure fugitive
S'enivre de volupté."
https://lyricstranslate.com

Comment: I have a friend of mine who has a singing diploma at Conservatory, I can ask her, I think she can tell me the correct interpertation.

Comment: @BakerStreet: Thanks for your research about this! It's indeed ambiguous and I agree that librettists' Italian is often laboured and unnatural (I'd like to exempt Metastasio, as a kind of forerunner of them all).

Comment: Thank to you for the interesting discussion!